# Decoding Custom CRC algorithm for a fiscal printer

Tags: php, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, crc

I've hit a brick wall here and I need your help. I have a fiscal printer (Datecs DP-50) to integrate on a chrome extension app that makes sales. The problem is that we can't use the driver since the app will run a on a remote server and not on the operators devices and we have to send the data raw.
The App coded in PHP using Laravel 5.1 as extra info.

So I have a CRC base 16 with a custom polynom x^15+1 but it's a bit more than that, and I cannot figure it out. I will paste in below the documentation from the manual.

```
   The two CRC bytes are calculated according to the formula x^15 + 1. In the 
    calculation are included all data bytes plus the byte for block end. Every byte passes 
    through the calculation register from teh MSB to LSB.
    Three working bytes are used - S1, S0 and TR
    S1 - Most significant byte from the CRC ( it is transmitted immediatelly after END)
    S0 - Least significant byte from the CRC ( It is transmitted after S1)
    TR - the current transmitted byte in the block.

    The CRC is calculated as follows:
    1. S1 and S0 are zeroed
    2. TR is loaded with the current transmitted byte. The byte is transmitted.
    3. Points 3.1 and 3.2 are executed 8 times:
    3.1. S1, S0 and TR are shifted one bit to the left.
    3.2. If the carry bit from S1 is 1, the MSB of S1 and LSB of S0 are inverted.
    Points 2 and 3 are executed for all bytes, included in the calculation of the CRC - from 
    the first byte after BEG up to and including byte END.
    4. TR is loaded with 0 and point 3 is executed
    5. TR is loaded with 0 and point 3 is executed
    6. Byte S1 is transmitted
    7. Byte S0 is transmitted
```

For example the CRC (Only S1 and S0) for "A" string is in hex: fe 09. For "B" => fc 09, for "C" => 7d f6. The complete CRC would be 0d fe 09 for "A".
TR from the Serial COM Monitor seems to be a constant and always represented as 0d hex.

Any help decoding this is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description is flawed, aside from the misspellings, in that it misses the crucial detail that the S1, S0, TR registers, in that order, are to be treated as a single 24-bit register when shifting left. If you do that, then you get the results you quote. You need to include the `0x0d` in the calculation (the "END" byte).

```
function crc16($crc, $byte) {
    $crc = ($crc << 8) + $byte;
    for ($k = 0; $k < 8; $k++)
        $crc = ($crc & 0x800000) == 0 ? $crc << 1 : ($crc << 1) ^ 0x800100;
    $crc = ($crc >> 8) & 0xffff;
    return $crc;
}

$crc = 0;
$crc = crc16($crc, ord("A"));
$crc = crc16($crc, 13);
$crc = crc16($crc, 0);
$crc = crc16($crc, 0);
echo dechex($crc);
```

gives `fe09`.

Comment: Sorry about that, my knowledge of low level programming is quite limited and english is not my native language. 

Yes, I omitted to put the END byte in the calculation, thus my wrong results.
I found a js implementation of the the algorythm here also: http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html . Inspect element for the js code.

Thanks Mark!